# wiki page library migration to office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2007, wiki-pages

Is it possible to just copy and paste the wiki page library from Sharepoint 2007 on premise to Sharepoint Online 365?

Comment: what's the easiest way to migrate or at least get a working copy of the on premise wiki to SP Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good idea to copy and paste the Wiki pages from 2007 to office 365. You better use migrations tools to migrate the pages so that content also will migrate as expected.

You can use Share gate free trail to move the wiki pages. here is the link to download the setup file and you need to provide correct email(it won't accept gmail or yahoo mail) so that you will get the license https://en.share-gate.com/download

Comment: i tried and it worked. I'm using a trial key but it said that if u use a trial some items might not uploaded or moved, but then when i checked the item count in site contents, its exactly the same so I'm wondering if its really a trial....

Comment: It will say like that but it does all migration.. :). Can you vote for this and select answer :)

Comment: weird, I'm just quite afraid if the trial ends, would the finished/migrated items be deleted, revoked, or something?

Comment: question: I got this message during migration saying: The insane mode does not support copying aspx ... does that mean that the wiki page did not copy over? I checked it but I think it did copy..however Im wondering what is that message about....

Comment: Insane mode is not require to enable. through normal mode also it will copy. difference between normal and insane is it increases the speed in insane mode as it uses the share point jobs to migrate bulk content.

Comment: am i right that if the items have been migrated/copied already to our SPOnline, it will no longer be deleted in any means/ways by Sharegate when our trial license expires??

Comment: Yes it won't delete any items or pages or documents once it is migrated to destination.you don't worry about it.

Comment: Can you vote for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I work for Sharegate :) I can confirm that no, we do not delete anything once the Free Trial ends!